# Is there a cleaner way to use JavaScriptSerializer.Deserialize(json)?

Tags: c#, .net

Is there a nicer way to do this?

```
JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
Dictionary<string, object> dic =
    jss.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, object>>(json);
Dictionary<string, object>.Enumerator enumerator = dic.GetEnumerator();
enumerator.MoveNext();
ArrayList arr = (ArrayList)enumerator.Current.Value;
foreach (Dictionary<string, object> item in arr)
{
    string compID = item["compID"].ToString();
    string compType = item["compType"].ToString();
}
```

All I want is my array of items (i.e. comp)

I am sending a json like this:

```
{ "comps" : [ { compID : 1 , compType : "t" } , { ect. } ] }
```

Comment: there's a couple of thrid party libraries that will help clean this up: try http://json.codeplex.com/ and http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/159450/fastJSON

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is there a nicer way to do this?

Yes, by defining models:

```
public class MyModel
{
    public IEnumerable<Comp> Comps { get; set; }
}

public class Comp
{
    public int CompId { get; set; }
    public string CompType { get; set; }
}
```

and then deserialize the JSON string to this model so that you can work with strong types, not some dictionaries of magic strings:

```
JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
MyModel model = jss.Deserialize<MyModel>(json);
foreach (Comp comp in model.Comps)
{
    // Do something with comp.CompId and comp.CompType here
}
```

Comment: note for the reader - the names in the model and the json need to be exactly the same (i tried to change and poof), and i believe that the reason using capitals is cuz its props that actually create a var with the same name non capital am i right about that?